# applescript: determine the date of last Sunday

Tags: applescript

I need to take today's date and work backwards to Sunday and get that date.  so, for instance today is Monday, December 16.  I need to know that the previous Sunday was December 15.

I've tried several different approaches

```
set theDate to ((current date) - 1)
repeat until (weekday of theDate) = Sunday
    set theDate to theDate - 1 * days
end repeat
```

but have not had any luck.

Comment: Interestingly, the method you've written _does_ actually work!  You don't need to subtract `1` from the `current date` in the first line (though it also doesn't do any harm), but I ran it as is, and it worked just fine.  In fact, it's an elegant solution.

Comment: Thank you!  I will try to figure out why it didn't work for me.

Answer (score 2):

The following *example* **AppleScript** *code* works for me in **macOS High Sierra** and will return the *date string* of the previous Sunday:

```
set now to (current date)

if weekday of now is Monday then
    return date string of (now - 86400)
else if weekday of now is Tuesday then
    return date string of (now - 86400 * 2)
else if weekday of now is Wednesday then
    return date string of (now - 86400 * 3)
else if weekday of now is Thursday then
    return date string of (now - 86400 * 4)
else if weekday of now is Friday then
    return date string of (now - 86400 * 5)
else if weekday of now is Saturday then
    return date string of (now - 86400 * 6)
else if weekday of now is Sunday then
    return date string of (now - 86400 * 7)
end if
```

Comment: @Charles Hawkins, `86400` is the number of seconds in 24 hours.

Comment: You can also work with 'days' as an alternative to 'seconds', e.g. return date string of (now - 2 * days). See Class Reference in the ASLG for details: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_classes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH1g-BBCGECID

Answer (score 1):

This handler will let you pass in any date, and return back to you the date of the Sunday that came just before it.  In the example below, I've applied this to the current date.

```
my lastSundayBefore:(current date)
    --> date "Sunday, 15 December 2019 at 23h44m36"

on lastSundayBefore:(now as {date, text})
    local now

    if class of now = text then tell (the current date) ¬
        to set [day, [its month, day, year], time, now] ¬
        to [1, [word 2, word 3, word 1] of now, 0, it]

    set yesterday to now - days
    set today to the weekday of yesterday
    set lastSunday to yesterday + (1 - today) * days
end lastSundayBefore:
```

The handler takes a single parameter—-the date relative to which you wish to know the previous Sunday's date—-and this can be an AppleScript `date` object, or an ISO-8601 formatted string, i.e. `"YYYY-MM-DD"`.

For example:

```
get its lastSundayBefore:"2019-10-31"
```

which, on my system, returns:

```
date "Sunday, 27 October 2019 at 00h00m00"
```

---

I saw your solution you thought didn't work, which in fact it did, and I think it is actually the best.  It's simple, it's elegant, and it's easy to understand:

```
set theDate to the current date
repeat until (theDate's weekday) = Sunday
    set theDate to theDate - 1 * days
end repeat
```

A recursive form of this just for fun:

```
on lastSundayBefore:(now as date)
    local now

    tell (now - days)
        if its weekday = Sunday then return it
        return my lastSundayBefore:it
    end tell
end lastSundayBefore:
```